# What explicit type casts should I add to make a no operator method work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-geocoder, rails-postgresql, pg

I'm trying to use the `near` method of the Ruby geocoder gem in a Rails application with a postgres database.

```
 @users = Contact.near(params[:search], params[:distance])
```

That line produces the 'operator does not exist error' you see below. The search parameter will be an address and the dist

In the Contact.rb model I do this

```
geocoded_by :full_address

 def full_address

   self.address + self.city + self.province + self.postal
 end
```

Can you tell me what it is that I might be doing wrong? The error says, 'You might need to add explicit type casts.'

`Address`, `city`, `province` and `postal` are all strings.

```
PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric - character varying LINE 1: ...8.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.7058645 - contacts... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT contacts.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.7058645 - contacts.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(43.7058645 * PI() / 180) * COS(contacts.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-79.3687137 - contacts.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(contacts.longitude - -79.3687137), RADIANS(contacts.latitude - 43.7058645))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM "contacts" WHERE (contacts.latitude BETWEEN 43.676918143377826 AND 43.73481085662217 AND contacts.longitude BETWEEN -79.40875589075141 AND -79.3286715092486 AND 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.7058645 - contacts.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(43.7058645 * PI() / 180) * COS(contacts.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-79.3687137 - contacts.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) <= '2') ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If `contacts.longitude` and `contacts.latitude` are strings, you need to cast them.

Comment: @Denis thanks that worked changing them to floats